# SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL - the connection has been disabled error

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Migrating 1.6m rows from MySQL 5.5 to SQL Server 2012. I've attempted to migrate the data on several occasions and the process fails after an even number of rows. I've tried with different batch sizes and timeouts and I've failed after migrating 55,000 rows, 44,000 rows, 55,000 rows, and finally 42,000 rows.

Does anyone have experience in migrating successfully?

Most recent error below.

```
The data migration engine is migrating table 'source_db.table': > target_db.dbo.table, 1688992 rows total
The connection has been disabled.
 Errors: The connection has been disabled.
Completing migration of table source_db.table...
Migration complete for table 'source_db.table': > target_db.dbo.table, 42000 rows migrated (Elapsed Time = 00:00:04:03:856).
Data migration operation has finished.
    0 table(s) successfully migrated. 
    1 table(s) partially migrated. 
    0 table(s) failed to migrate.
```

Comment: are SQL server and MySQL on the same box?

Comment: Different boxes. SQL Server is an AWS RDS instance we're connecting through a tunnel and MySQL is on a local machine.

Comment: Same issue here with MySQL 5.6 and Azure SQL: 

    Data migration operation has finished.
     46 table(s) successfully migrated. 
     7 table(s) partially migrated. 
     215 table(s) failed to migrate.
        
and the same message:
    Errors: The connection has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I increased the  CPU cores from 1 to 8 in my Virtual Machine where I am running the SSMA to migrate from MySql to MsSql. It Worked for me.